# What is the relationship between winmd files in different directories

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, winmd

I'm working on Windows Store Apps development, and I found winmd files in different directories of Windows.

When developing a Windows Store App, the App is referencing **Windows.winmd** file under:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral*

But I could also find several different winmd files under:

*C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata*

My question is what's the relationship between winmd files under these two different directories?

I guess the big **Windows.winmd** file is used at compile time to build appx package, and the separated winmd files under *C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata* is used at runtime?

Also, why not having one big **Windows.winmd** file under *C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata* too ?